# Complicated grouping query, finding a ID not part of the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I am having a bit of trouble with this SQL query, first some background

Table definition

```
create table [owner]
(
  [patientid] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
  [clientid] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
  [percentage] float NULL,
  [status] bit NOT NULL
)

alter table [owner] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_OWNER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([patientid],[clientid])
```

Example source data

```
| PATIENTID | CLIENTID | PERCENTAGE | STATUS |
----------------------------------------------
|      Pet1 |   Owner1 |        100 |      1 |
|      Pet2 |   Owner2 |         75 |      1 |
|      Pet2 |   Owner3 |         25 |      1 |
|      Pet3 |   Owner4 |         10 |      1 |
|      Pet3 |   Owner5 |         90 |      1 |
|      Pet3 |   Owner6 |        100 |      0 |
|      Pet4 |   Owner7 |         50 |      1 |
|      Pet4 |   Owner8 |         50 |      1 |
```

What I am looking for is I want the owner who has the highest percentage per pet who has a status of `1`, in the event of a tie, it should go alphabetically by the Owner's name.

So here is the output I would want to see

```
| PATIENTID | CLIENTID |
------------------------
|      Pet1 |   Owner1 |
|      Pet2 |   Owner2 |
|      Pet3 |   Owner5 |
|      Pet4 |   Owner7 |
```

The closest I got was

```
SELECT f1.[patientid]
      ,f1.[clientid]
  FROM [OWNER] f1
inner join 
(
  select [patientid], max([percentage]) as [percentage]
  from [owner]
  where status = 1
  group by [patientid]
) f2 on f1.[patientid] = f2.[patientid] and f1.[percentage] = f2.[percentage]
where status = 1
```

However that gives me two records for `Pet4`.

```
| PATIENTID | CLIENTID |
------------------------
|      Pet1 |   Owner1 |
|      Pet2 |   Owner2 |
|      Pet3 |   Owner5 |
|      Pet4 |   Owner7 |
|      Pet4 |   Owner8 |
```

What is the correct way to handle something like this so I only get one record and I apply that alphabetical ordering on the tie to find the one record?

Here is a [SQL Fiddle workspace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8b5c) to try out any answers.

---

**EDIT:**

I figured a way how to do it, but to me it reeks of code smell, is there a more "proper" way of doing this?

```
select distinct f3.[patientid], (
  SELECT top 1 f1.[clientid]
    FROM [OWNER] f1
  inner join 
  (
    select [patientid], max([percentage]) as [percentage]
    from [owner]
    where status = 1
    group by [patientid]
  ) f2 on f1.[patientid] = f2.[patientid] and f1.[percentage] = f2.[percentage]
  where status = 1 and f1.[patientid] = f3.[patientid]
  order by f1.[patientid], f1.[clientid]
)
from owner f3
```

Comment: bluefeet's solution is better: the server will read the rows just one time. For above solution, the server will read the rows two/three times: `f1`, `f2`, `f3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `row_number()` to get the result by applying a partition by the `patientid` and ordering it by the percentage and clientid:

```
select patientid, clientid
from
(
  select patientid, clientid, percentage, status,
    row_number() over(partition by patientid 
                      order by percentage desc, clientid) rn
  from owner
  where status = 1
) d
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8b5c/7)

Comment: Ah, much better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the windowing functions, as in the answer from @bluefeet, make this easier to read. But you were close to the alternative syntax. MIN() can resolve the alphabetical ordering on tied rows.  (Some people imagine that MIN() operates only on numbers.)

```
SELECT f1.[patientid]
     , MIN(f1.[clientid])
FROM [OWNER] f1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT [patientid], max([percentage]) as [percentage]
     FROM [owner]
     WHERE status = 1
     GROUP BY [patientid]
    ) f2 
ON  f1.[patientid] = f2.[patientid] 
AND f1.[percentage] = f2.[percentage]
GROUP BY f1.patientid
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery will also work, though partition may scale better

```
declare @tmpOwner table (
    PatientID varchar(50),
    ClientID varchar(50),
    Percentage int,
    Status smallint
)

insert @tmpOwner (PatientID,ClientID,Percentage,Status)
SELECT 'Pet1','Owner1',100,1 UNION
SELECT 'Pet2','Owner2',75,1 UNION
SELECT 'Pet2','Owner3',25,1 UNION
SELECT 'Pet3','Owner4',10,1 UNION
SELECT 'Pet3','Owner5',90,1 UNION
SELECT 'Pet3','Owner6',100,0 UNION
SELECT 'Pet4','Owner7',50,1 UNION
SELECT 'Pet4','Owner8',50,1


select x.PatientID,
(SELECT top 1 ClientID 
 FROM @tmpOwner 
 where Percentage=max(x.Percentage) 
 and x.PatientID=PatientID
 order by ClientID) Win_Owner
from @tmpOwner x
where x.Status=1
group by PatientID
```